# Does Android 4.3 fix USB OTG on Nexus 4 when used with an external power source?

Tags: nexus-4, usb-on-the-go

It seems to be fairly well established that the Nexus 4 has had issues with not supporting USB OTG since launch (e.g. [this bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=40087)).  From what I've read it's both a hardware and software issue.  The hardware can't supply the necessary power and the software does not conform to the protocol in some way.  I'm happy to use a Nexus 4 with an **external** power source (Y-cable), which should solve the power issue.  What I'd like to establish though is, *does Android 4.3 do anything to fix the **software** issue?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, 4.3 doesn't address that at all.  You'll still have to use the kernel that [Ziddey has posted on xda-developers.com](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2181820).